# password checker showing unlock for (0,0,0) but not for given number(password)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```js
import React ,{useState}from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const password =[2,2,3];
  const [digits ,setDigits]=useState([0,0,0]);
  const [isUnlocked,setIsUnlocked]=useState(false);



  let setDigitAtIndex=(digit,idx)=>{
    setDigits((currentDigits)=>
      [
        ...currentDigits.slice(0, idx),
        digit,
        ...currentDigits.slice(idx  + 1)
      ]
    );
  };
  let checkPassword=() =>{
    for (let i=0;i<password.length;i++){
      if(password[i]===digits[i]){
        return;
      }
    }
    setIsUnlocked(true);

  }
  return (
    <section>
    <h1>Passo</h1>
      <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
      <input type="number" value={digits[0]}
       onChange={(event) => setDigitAtIndex(parseInt(event.target.value),0)}/> 


      <input type="number" value={digits[1]}
           onChange={(event)=>setDigitAtIndex(parseInt(event.target.value),1)}/>
      <input type="number" value={ digits[2]}
            onChange={(event)=>setDigitAtIndex(parseInt(event.target.value),2)}/>




      </div>
      <button onClick={()=>checkPassword()}>Press Me</button>
      { isUnlocked && <p>Unlocked</p>}
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

after running this app in react when i click on press me button with 0 0 0 then it is showing unlocked but after typing 2 2 3 it is not working but it should be work after typing 223 help needed ?And any guys who is learning react those can answer this question

Comment: `if(password[i]===digits[i]){
        return;
      }` If it matches, exit.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let setDigitAtIndex=(digit,idx)=>{
    let temp = [...digits];
    temp[idx] = digit;
    setDigits(temp);
  };
```

this looks much easier?

also your checkpassword function is not correct.

replace `===` with `!==`

```
let checkPassword=() =>{
    for (let i=0;i<password.length;i++){
      if(password[i]!==digits[i]){
        setIsUnlocked(false);   // if the password is wrong, it will hide the text again
        return;
      }
    }
    setIsUnlocked(true);

  }
```

Comment: Approved as answer